# Call API on receiving FCM data only notification. IOS , on Background or terminated state

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can I call API when receiving fcm data only notification. when IOS app is not running.

P.S. It works on foreground on iOS and work perfectly on Android too.

I tried and found that it is not possible so i am asking if is it true or not.

Comment: It is true, it is not possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS, the only way you can guarantee you're app will run on receipt of a push is to use a Voip Push, however if you're not delivering legitimate Voip functionality your app would be rejected on submission to the App Store.

Otherwise you could send a user directed push and implement a notification service extension (if you don't want the user to see the notification it can be suppressed if you request and are granted an entitlement to be able to suppress them, that entitlement can be requested via your Apple account)
On receipt of the push the notification service extension will run, it can't launch the app however it can do plenty of things other than just intercept a push notification (including it can update databases that the app uses, or leave a note for the app so that next time the app runs it knows there was a push, download or upload content via http etc. to name a few examples).

Whether this approach is useful depends what it is that you need to be done, when the app isn't running, that can't be done immediately upon next launch.

What is the purpose of trying to do something when the app is terminated?

Comment: In my code i wanna check if user has internet or not. To do so I used fcm notification and on receiving it, I called an Api from app, so in server side if that api called then user status changed to online  if not user is offline. However i found that in IOS on receiving fcm notification , api is not executing.

Comment: If you need this to occur when the app is terminated, then in iOS the only option is for the app to receive the push in a notification server extension and make that api call, and you'll need to suppress the push notification from being displayed as visible notification to the user