# how to show notifications on phone devices with flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, push-notification

Hello every one I'm trying to build my own system for showing notifications in my flutter projects however, I want to achieve this without using FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) or any service like it, what I tried is to write a function that will listen to my database and when a new data is entered to the notification table it will use this data and show the notification , the problem that I faced is when the application is closed this function will be terminated I tried to use flutter background service package to run the function in the background but I faced two things , the first one is that the function sometimes works and sometimes gives some java errors -the application is running on android device- and the second one is that when the function is running in the background correctly without any errors the device care notified me that this app is working in the background and it consumes energy , any ideas how can I achieve my goal in a way like the whatsapp notifications ? appreciate your help .

Comment: The the inbuilt platform notification services on iOS and Android. FCM is a wrapper for these but there are other services. Why would you want to reinvent the wheel? WhatsApp and other apps would just be using the platform services (probably not via FCM)

Comment: @Paulw11 These platforms are not available in some countries, including mine. 
because of that I need to create my own . I know that FCM also runs a kind of background tasks, and I'm looking for more information about how. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Where is the database located? In the server? You want your apps to be notified when there is a server based change to the database? Android and iOS are very different in terms of notifications and you need to deal with that, and particularly the limitations with iOS. Just because your app is written is Flutter does not mean every part of it has to be. To give an idea of notification limitations on iOS see this answer I wrote this morning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77228058/call-api-on-receiving-fcm-data-only-notification-ios-on-background-or-termina

Comment: @Piepants Sorry if I was unclear. I have a database on a server with a table for notifications. I want to create a system where when a new row is added to the table, a notification is displayed on the user's device. The body and title of the notification should be taken from the row in the table. I'm also wondering how FCM-like platforms handle notifications when the app is in the background.

Comment: It might be worthwhile splitting your question into new separate ones, questions which are too broad in scope don't get a lot of attention/answers. One of your questions is how in the server to send notifications to both Android and iOS writing your own solution. For this first you need to study how pushes are sent on the two platforms and get a solid base of understanding, and it's a server question really . Then your also asking about how the apps can deal with the pushes and backgrounding, so that's a separate issue, and its different for the two platforms too, so maybe three question here.

Comment: I know you want to bundle all your questions up in one, especially as your apps are in flutter, but the server side and the app side really are different questions.  And as  Android and iOS are so different, you will probably have to implement the push handling and background aspects natively, providing some simple Flutter API to the Flutter parts of the app as appropriate. It's a big thing, you need to split it into smaller chunks so you can get focused answers. And before you can ask very specific questions you need to study native push sending and  handling on the two platforms first IMO.

Comment: @Piepants Thanks for your suggestions.  I know I talked alot , however the notifications are working well when the app is foreground and I'm wondering how to make it work in the background as well , so my question is how does the FCM handel the background listening for the notifications in flutter project so I use the same mechanism in my project

Comment: The answer is your app is nothing to do with sending the notifications.  You do that from your server.  If you don't want to use a service like FCM then your server can talk directly to Apple and Google's push notification services. - e.g. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns.

Comment: FCM doesn't use "background listening".  The FCM server sends a platform-specific push message using the Google/Apple service.  This is then delivered to the relevant device via that service.

Answer (score 0):

As you already found out, you can send messages without firebase, but it is impossible to do without draining the battery at least a bit. Also it's more complicated. That's why most apps use FCM.
The option you have is either use a package or implement it yourself with platform channels. Since your package gives java errors, the latter option seems more suitable.
The go-to option would be to build a service that runs in the background and periodically checks for new messages.
If battery drain is too high, wait longer before checking again if possible

Comment: Does  the platform channels the same way that the FCM handel the background listening for the notifications ? 
Thanks for your help

Comment: The channel itself is just for using platform specific code (which we need here).
I'm not exactly sure how FCM works, but to my knowledge not every app is checking for notifications itself but the play services do that. This also mitigates the problem of being stopped by the system or draining too much battery.
The easiest and most reliable way would be to use FCM like everyone else